# Interrupt and return repetition within the while multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not new here but I also do not ask questions because whenever I have a problem I find a solution in questions related here in the forum or in blogs, but I did not have any success with this problem.

In a database I have the tables posts and categories that are related, and in a single MySQL query I am displaying the title of the posts within their categories. So far so good, everything working. However within the while loop structure the  tag with the is-sub class can not be repeated. Is there any way to stop the repetition of this while and then repeat it again?

I thank you for your help

```
echo '
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>';
$sql = Query("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON post_category = category_id ORDER BY post_category, post_title");

$is_category = NULL; 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) :

    if ($row['post_category'] != $is_category) {

        echo '<li class="has-sub"><a href="#" class="opendown">' . $row['category_title'] . '</a>';

        $is_category = $row['post_category'];

    }
        // stop loop
            echo '<ul class="is-sub">';
                // return loop
                echo '<li><a href="?doc=' . $row['post_id'] . '">' . $row['post_title'] . '</a></li>';
            // stop loop
            echo '</ul>';
        // return loop
        echo '</li>';

endwhile;
echo '
    </ul>
</nav>';
```

Comment: Can't you use a simple flag like you used for `$is_category`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to do, I think the code below would work. If the `is_sub` tag is really meant to show only once then this could work:

```
<?php
echo '
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>';
$sql = Query("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON post_category = category_id ORDER BY post_category, post_title");

$is_category = NULL; 
$issub = false;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) :

    if ($row['post_category'] != $is_category) {

        echo '<li class="has-sub"><a href="#" class="opendown">' . $row['category_title'] . '</a>';

        $is_category = $row['post_category'];
        echo '<ul class="is-sub">';

    }
        if(!$issub) {
            echo '<ul class="is-sub">';
            $issub = true;
        }
        echo '<li><a href="?doc=' . $row['post_id'] . '">' . $row['post_title'] . '</a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';

endwhile;
echo '
    </ul>
</nav>';
?>
```

Comment: The addition of your code worked for @Paulo, this caused the loop to stop repeating the <ul is-sub> tag, but I asked the wrong one, I'm sorry. It has to repeat within all <li class = has-sub>

Comment: @WellingtonPragidi I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to explain my problem in detail, but finally I managed to solve it, your answer to my question was very useful, April my mind and with that the code is working as it should.

Comment: `<nav class="navbar"><ul>
$sql = Query("SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON post_category = category_id ORDER BY post_category, post_title");
    $is_category = '';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) :
  if($is_category != $row['category_title']) {
   if($is_category != '') {echo '</ul></li>';}
   echo '
   <li class="has-sub">' . $row['category_title'] .
       '<ul class="is-sub">';
   $is_category = $row['category_title'];
  }
  echo '<li><a href="?doc=' . $row['post_id'] . '">' . $row['post_title'] . '</a></li>';
 endwhile; ?>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>';